# double free or corruption (out) while deallocating memory in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a function which returns a 2D array in c++ as follows

```
float** Input_data(float** train_data, int Nv, int N){
float** x_train=new float*[Nv];

int a = 0,b = 0;
for(a = 1;a<= Nv;a++){

    x_train[a] = new float[N+1];

    for(b = 1; b <= N+1; b++){
        if(b == 1){

            x_train[a][b] = 1;

        }else{

        x_train[a][b] = train_data[a][b-1];

        }
    }return x_train;}
```

the purpose of the above code is to add ones in the first column and add remaining data from train_data pointer into x_train. after processing and using x_train i am trying to deallocate x_train as follows

```
void destroyx_array(float**x_train,int Nv){

for (int free_x = 1;free_x <= Nv;free_x++){
delete[] x_train[free_x];}delete[] x_train;}
```

and calling the destroy function as follows

```
destroyx_array(x_train,Nv)
```

the Input_data functions works fine but when i try to destroy_x_array it gives me double free or corruption(out) aborted (core dumped) can anybody explain what wrong i am doing ? thank you

Comment: In C++, array indexes start with 0, not 1. Memory corruption. `x_train[]` array access if off by 1, illegal memory access. Undefined behavior. You need to force yourself into using 0-based array indexes, otherwise these kinds of errors and bugs will continue to happen.

Comment: To add, the other kind of bug when faking arrays starting at 1 is that the `0` entry is used by mistake, making the program use an entry that shouldn't have been used.

Comment: Stop using raw pointers, then you will never get this sort of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, your code corrupts memory. The best thing is to not use raw pointers and instead use container classes such as `std::vector`.

Having said that, to fix your current code, the issue is that you're writing beyond the bounds of the memory here:

`for(a = 1;a<= Nv;a++)`

when `a == Nv`, you are writing one "row" beyond what was allocated.  This looks like a manifestation of attempting to fake 1-based arrays.  Arrays in C++ start from 0, not 1.  Trying to fake 1-based arrays invariably can lead to bugs and memory corruption.

The fix is to rewrite your function to start from 0, not 1, and ensure your loop iterates to `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of rows:

`for (a = 0; a < Nv; ++a)`

---

> the purpose of the above code is to add ones in the first column and
>   add remaining data from train_data pointer into x_train

Instead of the loop you wrote to test for the first column, you could simplify this by simply using `memcpy`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Nv; ++i)
 {
     x_train[i][0] = 1;
     memcpy(&x_train[i][1], &train_data[i][0], N * sizeof(float));
 }
```

Thus the entire function would look like this:

```
float** Input_data(float** train_data, int Nv, int N)
{
    float** x_train=new float*[Nv];
    for(int a = 0; a < Nv; a++)
       x_train[a] = new float[N+1];
    for (int a = 0; a < Nv; a++)
    {
       x_train[i][0] = 1;
       memcpy(&x_train[i][1], &train_data[i][0], N * sizeof(float));
    } 
    return x_train;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank for your reply. i was trying to replicate the matlab code into c++ so for ease of comparison i started from 1 rather than 0. I tried changing 1 to 0 for one part of the for loop as you guys said and it didn't output me any corruption error. I will change all of my codes for loop to start form 0 rather than 1. Also i will change the raw pointers to container classes as you mentioned. Thank you